# php imap badse64 decoded hebrew text

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap, hebrew

Hope someone can help.
I'm writing an app that fetches emails from gmail. The emails are in Hebrew.
I used [This script](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-message-body-attachments/) to fetch email body. 
All emails have case 3 or 4 of the following script :

```
switch($encoding) {
    case 0: return $data; // 7BIT
    case 1: return $data; // 8BIT
    case 2: return $data; // BINARY
    case 3: return base64_decode($data); // BASE64
    case 4: return quoted_printable_decode($data); // QUOTED_PRINTABLE
    case 5: return $data; // OTHER
}
```

and most of emails decoded using `base64_decode($data)` and some using `quoted_printable_decode($data)`.
The result I'm getting varies, some of the messages decoded properly, and some have only html text and english text decode but Hebrew comes in `U+FFFD or ���� ���� ��� ���� �` like this.

Comment: And what charset is your data in?  If it doesn't match your HTML charset, you'll need to transcode it. This should be part of your Content-Type header: Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8", for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It appeared some emails where html messages, and charset was changed, the following code sorted this problem
[code]if(htmlspecialchars($data) == "")
  $data = iconv("iso-8859-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $data);[code]